# Calculate the average values of a column that has duplicate timestamps in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
 df_temperature_value = {'timestamp': ['2020-08-08 12:00:00', '2020-08-08 13:00:00', '2020-08-08 14:00:00',
                                          '2020-08-09 12:00:00', '2020-08-09 13:00:00', '2020-08-09 14:00:00',
                                          '2020-08-08 12:00:00', '2020-08-08 13:00:00', '2020-08-08 14:00:00', 
                                          '2020-08-09 12:00:00', '2020-08-09 13:00:00', '2020-08-09 14:00:00'],
                      'locations':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,],
                      'value':[20,21,22,23,24,25,16,17,18,19,20,21]
                     }

df_temperature_value= pd.DataFrame(df_temperature_value)
df_temperature_value['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temperature_value["timestamp"])
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to find the average value for each duplicated timestamp.

Quick example: Location 1 has at 2020-08-08 12:00:00 a value = 20 and Location 2 on the same duration has  a value equal to 16. So I need to find the average on this period of time which will be 18.

My final dataframe should look something like this:

```
  final_dataframe = {'timestamp': ['2020-08-08 12:00:00', '2020-08-08 13:00:00', '2020-08-08 14:00:00',
                                          '2020-08-09 12:00:00', '2020-08-09 13:00:00', '2020-08-09 14:00:00'],
                      'average_values':[18,19,20,21,22,23]
                     }
    final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(final_dataframe)
```

What I tried to do is the following:

```
final_dataframe = df_temperature_value.set_index('timestamp').resample('H').min().reset_index()
```

But this doesn't give me what I want as an output. What is the best way to do it. Is there a pythonic way ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `df_temperature_value.groupby('timestamp')['value'].mean()`.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thank you so much. That's all I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df_temperature_value.groupby('timestamp')['value'].mean()`

[Steal comments that answer the question and post them as an answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931)